# How to utilise TypeScript Variadic Tuple Types for a Cartesian Product function?

Tags: typescript, cartesian-product, typescript4.0, variadic-tuple-types

TypeScript 4.0 started to support the notion of [Variadic Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html), a nice type construct that can be used in e.g. concatenation functions. An example from the docs:

```
type Arr = readonly any[];

function concat<T extends Arr, U extends Arr>(arr1: T, arr2: U): [...T, ...U] {
  return [...arr1, ...arr2];
}
```

I am interested in whether this type construct can be used to type a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) function.  The function should then infer the (mixed) types from the arguments to produce its return type. So if I input `[number[], string[]]` I would expect the output to be of type `[number, string][]`. Multiple implementations for a Cartesian Product can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript), but none is strictly typed. Here is an example:

```
const cartesian =
  (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
```

An implementation I currently use does not utilise Variadic Tuple Types and needs explicit type casting:

```
const cartesian = <T extends any[]>(...arr: any[][]): T[] =>
  arr.reduce<T[]>(
    (a, b) => a.flatMap<T>(c => b.map<T>(d => [...c, d] as T)),
    [[]] as T
  );

const product = cartesian<[number, string]>([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

I am looking for a solution without explicit type casting and I think Variadic Tuple Types may be the appropriate type construct here.

**Question**

How can I use Variadic Tuple Types to infer the types of a Cartesian Product function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think Variadic Tuple Types actually improves the way we can type this. Typing this has actually been possible since support for [mapping tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) was added in 3.1 (was probably possible before but not as cleanly).

You will still need a type assertion in the actual implementation, but the call site will infer the argument types and produce the correct return type:

```
type MapCartesian<T extends any[][]> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Array<infer U>? U: never
}
const cartesian = <T extends any[][]>(...arr: T): MapCartesian<T>[] =>
  arr.reduce(
    (a, b) => a.flatMap(c => b.map(d => [...c, d] )),
    [[]] 
  ) as MapCartesian<T>[];

const product = cartesian([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAwnATsCBnAlnAdgHgBUoIAPdXAEwyjxAG0BdJgPigF4oBvAKCinoAFKFlxQA1hBAB7AGZRCjAFwKhjEuQhUaAQRQo4IfKNkQUUAKosA-JZW4IANzM8AvjwDG03BmBQPqOjYeBxQRBoU1LS4DMyMLAAUAHQpqCgqhACUKvBIgZg4BIQsTBwsfLT6SSgQlACuHhAJFfwJcAA0UABGmWW0SbIANnDAuQkefV1JALYICZR99ClJHp2U6pmZ7S0CTOoVvXA0uchoBXhEJYwA3Dye3r5QYCjS9R5+nAFnwbgJ9ACMnQATJ0AMyMTr0ADkcChnShXThUChHihjEytx4QA)

Comment: Really nice solution! I came across with `function cartesian<A extends Array<Array<any>>>(...args: A): { [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Array<any> ? A[K][number] : never }[];` which worked for arrays, but your solution is definitely better as it allows the input "sets" to be of any type not necessarily arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If it's cartesian product we should rather use Set instead of arrays. Both for input as for output.

```
function cartesian<X, Y>(setX: Set<X>, setY: Set<Y>): Set<[X, Y]> {
    const result = new Set<[X, Y]>();
    setX.forEach(x => setY.forEach(y => result.add([x, y])));
    return result;
}

const product = cartesian(new Set([1, 2, 3]), new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

EDIT (after Nicky's comment):

I tried to generalize the function signature for any number of sets but, could not switch from array to set:

```
declare function cartesian<A extends Array<Array<any>>>(
    ...args: A): { [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Array<any> ? A[K][number] : never }[];
const product = cartesian([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false]);
```

but then I read carefully the answer by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, with nice type inference so I used his approach for sets:

```
declare function cartesian<A extends Array<Set<any>>>(
    ...args: A): Set<{ [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Set<infer T> ? T : never }>;
const product = cartesian(new Set([1, 2, 3]), new Set(['a', 'b', 'c']), 
    new Set([true, false]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that is not what the question is about.

Comment: @Nicky Ok, But by the way you need this for cartesian product of two "sets" ? or more?

Comment: I need an infinite amount of sets, so it should handle N different inputs (as opposed to two)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the original question. But the solution provided by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir seems to be perfectly ok, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As Titian said, Variadic Tuple Types aren't really necessary here. You can also achieve a more compact solution that Titian's by having the generic `T` represent the inner types of each input array. Also, you should use `unknown` as a safer alternative to `any`.

```
const cartesian = <T extends unknown[]>(...a: { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }) =>
    a.reduce<T[]>(
        (b, c) => b.flatMap((d) => c.map((e) => [...d, e] as T)),
        [[]] as unknown as T[]
    );
```