# How to do cartesian product with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, permutation, ramda.js

Here's the type signature that I'm after:

```
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>([c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8]: [T1[], T2[], T3[], T4[], T5[], T6[], T7[], T8[]]): [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>([c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7]: [T1[], T2[], T3[], T4[], T5[], T6[], T7[]]): [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>([c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6]: [T1[], T2[], T3[], T4[], T5[], T6[]]): [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>([c1, c2, c3, c4, c5]: [T1[], T2[], T3[], T4[], T5]): [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3, T4>([c1, c2, c3, c4]: [T1[], T2[], T3[], T4[]]): [T1, T2, T3, T4][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2, T3>([c1, c2, c3]: [T1[], T2[], T3[]]): [T1, T2, T3][];
function cartesianProduct<T1, T2>([c1, c2]: [T1[], T2[]]): [T1, T2][];
function cartesianProduct<T>(sets: T[][]): T[][] {
  // implementation
}
```

Here's an example of what I expect it to do. Given:

```
const input = [
  [ 'a', 'b' ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
];
```

It would spit out:

```
const output = [
  [ 'a', 1 ],
  [ 'a', 2 ],
  [ 'b', 1 ],
  [ 'b', 2 ],
];
```

Trying to utilize this [reference implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234242/592641) gives us this type problem:

[image]

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigQwE4wKYGc5oQAKGCAJmLADwAqAjADTI0BMTNAzOwCzsCs7AGzsA7OwAcAPgAUAbSiNUbVF1S9UA1MNRjU4gLoAuZLPqz97FufYdrzbnZp9HgxyMfjz%20gJTHTi1hsefiFRCX1zAG5QSFhEFHQsPAJiUgpqeksg%20xDmbRoRGXlFKGUoVSh1KE0obSgRIxMzC2YrFs5HB3bndtd2930fP0zW7Jp1J1DmBqiY6HgkVEwcfEISckoYWgDlTmDmTRpBIoUmUrOKqprBRv9HNptOxx6hL18mnbGJw5vZ8Hn4kskqtUhsMp9mKpxvwTiUypcznxbs1LI5bO0uvwhh8spD9k4Ivpov84otEisUut0lsRoE8fZYWd4WduMi6Pc0U9Bu9-Li9vZCcTYgsEstkms0pttnyOIylBc2Rz2ujsbzRpDBXNSaLgZTJeDLHLSor2m1VbSWJqSSKgRSJWCaTJcNgYLhjDRzOZ3h7CcgAN7AZDIAD0weQcAAtgAHAA22Aj2AgMDQNow2BAxgAFjAYFG3aHcMmoABrBAAN2wGBAMYQAHcAHRQBAR4NoYMcQQsDjcFg94N8ACcLEE3DogeQaZgYAwKGdrvrafS2Gk0gTEYQTDn3mQAF5JP7x0HJ9OUGuEPWI2go9IAB67-cBoNPicuk-IOcXq-SACe94Pz%20fY8Z2QG9GyQdAYDkb8fGiADkAAX28Q8EKQuCF2wJdpGteJpDQBgACNvD9F8p2AtAwOgFNpEIhCGC9cd4KYWQ3mieDgCAA).

Comment: Relevant: [Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989)

Comment: Certainly great pointer @VLAZ, thank you. Updated the question.

Comment: So can you use that logic? Anything more needed or is this duplicate?

Comment: @trincot Not a duplicate. The reference is not in TypeScript.

Comment: Sure, but the algorithm is there. What holds you back from implementing it in TypeScript? Did you encounter some problem? Any syntax issue?

Comment: @trincot yes. Updated the question to elaborate.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025411/how-to-utilise-typescript-variadic-tuple-types-for-a-cartesian-product-function , is this distinct from that?

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to use Ramda, you can use [`R.sequence`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sequence) with arrays.

```
const cartesianProduct = R.sequence(Array.of)

const input = [
  [ 'a', 'b' ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
];

cartesianProduct(input)
//=> [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

Comment: Very nice.  I forget to reach for `sequence` at times I really should.  This helps demonstrate its power.

Comment: This is probably the sexiest cartesianProduct implementation out there. It's unfortunately still not typed under [@types/ramda](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/ramda/src), so it doesn't "exist" in TypeScript.

Comment: @Daniel: Ramda is working on [bringing the TS typings in-house](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/3264), but it's not clear what parts of the FantasyLand specification (including `traverse` on which  `sequence` is based) are even possible to type in TypeScript.

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski if you don't need the more general nature of `R.sequence` anywhere else, I believe you could create the type signatures specialised to arrays in an ambient module within your own code. I suspect it doesn't exist in the @types/ramda because of the higher kinded types involved with the general form that are a pain to encode in Typescript.

e.g.
`declare module "ramda" { export function sequence<T1, T2>(fn: (a: T1) => [T1]): ([c1, c2]: [T1[], T2[]]) => [T1, T2][] }`

Answer (score 0):

For problems like these I always like to start with the types first.

First a type to extract the element type of an array:

```
type ElementType<A> = A extends ReadonlyArray<infer T> ? T : never;
```

Yes, I know `A[number]` exists but this will result in type errors later on because `A` will be a result from `infer`.

Then a type that takes a list of arrays and gives us their element types.

```
type ElementsOfAll<Inputs, R extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []> = Inputs extends readonly [infer F, ...infer M] ? ElementsOfAll<M, [...R, ElementType<F>]> : R;
```

It's almost like `Inputs.map((F) => ElementType(F))` in code.

Finally we use this type to define a CartesianProduct type:

```
type CartesianProduct<Inputs> = ElementsOfAll<Inputs>[];
```

Now that we did it in types it's time to do it in code:

```
function cartesianProduct(sets) {
  return sets.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
}
```

This amazing implementation was taken from this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053803/18244921) where you can find other alternatives if your environment does not support `flat` or `flatMap`.

After we have this implementation we add the types:

```
function cartesianProduct<Sets extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>>(sets: Sets): CartesianProduct<Sets> {
  return sets.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
}
```

But there is an error because the return type does not match the type of the `reduce` call. Unfortunately I don't know a good way to rid the error but if a cast is acceptable:

```
function cartesianProduct<Sets extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>>(sets: Sets): CartesianProduct<Sets> {
  return sets.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat()))) as CartesianProduct<Sets>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)